# How to pick between 2 numbers

Tags: java, math, random

I'm creating a program that includes picking between 2 numbers 1 and -1. Nothing in between

I tried using an or statement with || and a random variable but since I am new to java i may have done it incorrectly.

```
int a = 1
int b = -1
int pos = 1

while(pos > 1 && pos < 10)
        {
            pos = pos + b || c
            System.out.println(pos);
        }
```

Comment: For one, you should post code that compiles.  b || c is probably allowable for C bur not java.  It is a logical operator not mathematical.   For a random variable you need to use the Random class.  Here is a hint:  Random.nextBoolean()

Comment: I don't see a random variable. You probably want a random variable.

Comment: `int n = Math.random() > 0.5? 1 : -1;`

Comment: Since the question is not clear, maybe you can describe in pseudocode or plain description what kind of problem that you want to solve actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way since you are limiting it to two numbers.
Returns `-1` if `true` or `1` if `false`.

```
Random r = new Random();
int number = r.nextBoolean() ? -1 : 1;
System.out.println(number);
```

Note that you just need to create the `Random` instance once and can use it throughout the program.